# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: c#, кодировка, visual-studio

Использую 2010. Пишу на до-диез :3. Чтение из файла происходит нормально, сравнение строк также происходит верно, но русские буковки ушли из-за ошибки с кодировкой. Как исправить? Использую стандартный блокнот win7. в VS и блокноте ничего связанного с кодировкой никогда не менял. Заранее спасибо.

**Дополнено из комментария**.

Наверное, я не прав. Дополню. Входные данные из текста:

> Десятичное число 63 в некоторой системе счисления записывается как 120. Каково основание конечной системы счисления?

Выход из программы:

> `���������� ����� 63 � ��������� ������� ��������� ������������ ��� 120. ������ ��������� �������� ������� ���������?`

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, разобрался сам. просто перекодировал текст в txt из ANSI в Unicode.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло